# Does the monster in the "Big Lizard" disaster eat garbage (and does garbage attract him)?

Tags: simcity-2013

When my city got attacked by the Godzilla-like monster, there was a curious moment at the end where I thought he was eating the garbage at the dump. Immediately after he finished, he burrowed into the ground and went away.

I wasn't sure if I was just imagining things, until I noticed in a video that he seemed to be heading for that city's dump too.

Does the monster just come for the garbage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Big Lizard disaster is unlocked by burning 100 tons of garbage at an incinerator. This is from the [IGN guide on achievements:](http://www.ign.com/wikis/simcity/Achievements)

> **What's Cookin'?** - Burn 100 tons of garbage in an Incinerator at the
>   Garbage Dump to gain access to the Big Lizard disaster

In my personal experience so far, he has done the same thing to my city. He made a beeline for the garbage dump, causing death, fire, and destruction all along the way. After he ate a bunch of garbage, he burrowed into the ground and left. **Him eating garbage actually DOES decrease the amount of tons of garbage you have stored in your dump.**

It would seem that his appearance might become more likely with the more garbage you keep piled up, however, earlier tonight he appeared without a garbage dump at all.  His appearance was brief, he burrowed into the ground in a residential area, and was done. He sure is an interesting creature.

Comment: Interesting, I guess after unlocking What's Cookin'? no city is immune to it.

Comment: had the same thing happen in my city.

Comment: yep - lizard spawned, ran in a straight line through my city to the garbage dump, ate garbage and died.

Comment: @Louis unlocking a disaster allows you to start that disaster whenever you want.  Disasters still happen randomly whether unlocked or not.

Answer (score 0):

When he appears, whatever triggers the monster, wherever he pops up, he'll cause chaos in a path to dump and eats 8 tons of garbage before burrowing down and leaving... at least by my two observations ...those were consecutive days shortly after the block party 25k mission/quest